# Debian 10 Authentication error on sign in screen as soon as I click on my user name

Tags: debian, gnome, login

As it says in the title, I am using Debian 10 on my laptop and I am facing a bit of a situation, as I am stuck in a login loop. The system allows me to type in my password sometimes, but most of the time I just get a message saying "authentication error", which appears under the password field. The message appears after clicking on any username on the login screen and after a waiting period. There is no further input on my side, and the screen goes back to the login screen right afterwards and often freezes after that. I have tried to go into my user directory `cd /home/username` -> `ls -la` and used `chmod a+rwx *` as is suggested in this question: [Debian login loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32949111/debian-login-loop) (I know this is generally not a good idea, but I was getting desperate). I am using Gnome as my user interface. At this point I'd be glad about any kind of advice, as to where this problem could spring from!

Comment: How did you get to the point of being able "to go into my user directory" if you can't login?

Comment: The `chmod` was a really bad idea

Comment: @roaima I can login around every one out of 20 times after restarting my laptop. Completely agree in regards to the `chmod` :)

Comment: When you next manage to login, run `ls -lA` and look for files not owned by you - particularly those starting with a dot. Those need `chown`ing back to your user id

Comment: So I tried that, and it looks like I own all the files in that folder except for root... could the reason be something else?